# Python regex string match from file

Tags: python, regex, string, match, text-files

I have this a text file that resembles

> alpha alphabet alphameric

I would like to match just the first string `alpha', nothing else

I have the following code that attempts to match just the `alpha` string and get its line number

```
findWord = re.findall('\\ba\\b', "alpha")

with open(file) as myFile:
for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
    if findWord in line:

        print 'Found at line: ', num
```

However I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues in your code

1. `re.findall('\\ba\\b', "alpha")` gives a matched list but you are using in `if findWord in line` means using list in place of string . That's what the error you are getting
2. By giving `findWord = re.findall('\\ba\\b', "alpha")` you are searching for string `a` in alpha string which is not existing

Try this

```
import re
#findWord = re.findall('\\ba\\b', "alpha")
#print findWord
with open("data.txt") as myFile:
    for num,line in enumerate(myFile):
        if re.findall('\\balpha\\b', line):

            print 'Found at line: ', num+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may modify your code a bit

```
with open(file, 'r') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if 'alpha' in line.split():
            print 'Found at line', num
```

Output:

> Found at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "alpha alphabet alphameric"
data = re.findall("alpha(?=\s)", s)[0]
```

Output:

```
"alpha"
```

Comment: Im trying to match just the string "alpha" and nothing else, I worded my question wrong sorry! I have edited it.